# centralManager:didDiscover never called in background

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios10

I'm doing a `centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([myServiceUUID], options: nil)` in the background, but the according

`func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)`

is never called.

When the app is in foreground, everything works as expected. But when the app is in the background, that method is never called.

I do have the `bluetooth-central` background mode set.

What else could I be missing?

EDIT: I uploaded the code to Github: https://github.com/haemi/BeaconBLEPoc

Comment: Where is your `CBCentralManager` object held?  Is it a property of a view controller or do you have it on a singleton?

Comment: in the app delegate - as I thought it's the safest thing to do while testing

Comment: Then can you show some code?

Comment: I uploaded the code to Github, see my edit

Comment: What notifications do you get?  Have you set a breakpoint in `didDiscoverPeripheral` to confirm that it isn't called?  If you can't get the peripheral name your code in this function falls through silently.

Comment: it works when the app is in the foreground... and I should get at least the notification at https://github.com/haemi/BeaconBLEPoc/blob/master/BeaconBLEPOC/AppDelegate.swift#L139; but the last notification I get is https://github.com/haemi/BeaconBLEPoc/blob/master/BeaconBLEPOC/AppDelegate.swift#L131

Comment: Discovery in the background can be slower. Also, try making `sensorTagAdvertisingUUID3` a property instead of a local variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123359/discussion-between-swalkner-and-paulw11).